# Best way to Learn Objective-C and Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I want to learn about Interface Builder in association with Xcode. I know C as far as simple console applications are concerned. (Reading an input, printing statements, if functions...). I now want to be able to write programs where I can have different views, cameras, and buttons in my app. Where is the best place to learn things like these? More examples include in depth descriptions about IBOutlet, @interface, and things like that. So I can make a complex app. I understand that there won't be a "One-Source-For-All" but different links will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, start by learning a few things about the Objective-C language itself, and so, a few things about the C language as well.

This is the very first step, and it requires only a text editor and a working GCC version.

Then, learn about the Xcode environment, build settings, etc.

Once you know a few things about the language and the IDE, you can begin to learn how to code apps.

For iPhone development, you'll have to learn about Apple's MVC model.
Especially:

- notifications
- delegation system
- Views and view controllers
- Other MVC patterns, like navigation controllers, etc.

Try to look at Apple's provided examples. They will teach you the (very) basics.
Then try to customize, as well as understand what you are doing, and what's the logic behind it.

Then, dig deep into the UIKit framework.

That's for a coding perspective.
But always keep in mind you'll have to know how controls are made on the iPhone, and how views are arranged.

That view and view controller hierarchy is the key for everything...
Good luck : )

Comment: Thank you very much for your time in writing this answer. Really appreciate it! :D

Comment: You're welcome... And again, good luck. Or should I say, welcome...

Answer (score 2):

For a complete novice I would suggest the introduction videos at http://developer.apple.com/videos/iphone/ that includes introductions to important stuff such as:

- The SDK, and IDE.
- Key practices.
- Interface design.
- And much much more…

Then write apps! You can not learn tennis by reading about tennis. Nor can you learn iOS development by reading alone…

Answer (score 0):

The best way to learn is to check out open source projects and getting familiar with the Apple Doc's and Frameworks.